# C++ word counter

Tags: c++, cpu-word, counter

How can I change in this c++ code "char word[50]" to "string word[50]" because I want to count and calculate each words in text not only my input word. All calculation about TF/IDF calculation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

/**************************************************/
```

Here char word[50];

```
 int ch,match[3],cnt,i,cntt[3],matchh[3],occurence,flg[3];
 float tf,idf;
 char word[50],line[50];
 int nd=3,iterm;
 int doc[20];

 /**************************************************/

 void case1() 
 {

 FILE *fill[3];
 fill[1]=fopen("doc1.txt","r");
 fill[2]=fopen("doc2.txt","r"); 
 fill[3]=fopen("doc3.txt","r");
 match[i]=0;
 cnt=0;
```

I need to change here word , When I do char word[50] to string word[50] here giving some error

```
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
while(!feof(fill[i]))
{
fscanf(fill[i],"%s",line);
//  if(strcmp(line,word)==0)

   if(strstr(line,word)!=0)

   match[i]++;
   cntt[i]++;
}

fclose(fill[i]);

}

cout<<"\n----------------Total # of Word-------------------\n";

for(i=1;i<4;i++)

{

cout<<"\n Documant "<<i<<" = "<<cntt[i];

}

cout<<"\n\n------------------Term Counts--------------------\n";


cout<<word<<"  ";
cout<<"(";
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{

cout<<"Doc"<<i<<","<<match[i]<<" ; ";

}
cout<<")";
cout << "\n\n\n |  Words  |    D1     |    D2    |    D3    |  \n";
cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------\n";


 cout<<"     "<<word;

for(i=1;i<4;i++)

{

 tf=(float)match[i]/cntt[i];   //Term Frequency

 cout<<"      "<<tf;

}


cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
}

/**************************************************/

void case2() 
{
FILE *fill[3];
fill[1]=fopen("doc1.txt","r");
fill[2]=fopen("doc2.txt","r");
fill[3]=fopen("doc3.txt","r");
match[i]=0;
cnt=0;

cout<<"\n Total Number Of Documants => 3";
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
while(!feof(fill[i]))
{
    fscanf(fill[i],"%s",line);
    //  if(strcmp(line,word)==0)
    if(strstr(line,word)!=0)
    {
        match[i]++;
        matchh[i]++;
        flg[i]=1;
    }
    cnt++;
    cntt[i]++;
}

fclose(fill[i]);
}

cout<<"\n----------------Total # of Word-------------------\n";

for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{

 cout<<"\n Documant "<<i<<" are = "<<cntt[i];

}

cout<<"\n\n------------------Term Counts--------------------\n";

for(i=1;i<4;i++) 
{

cout<<"\n Documant "<<i<<" = "<<matchh[i];

}

for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
if(matchh[i]>0)
{

matchh[i]=1;
flg[i]=flg[i]+matchh[i];
occurence=occurence+flg[i];

}

else
matchh[i]=0;

}


tf=(float)3/occurence;
idf=log10(tf);

cout<<"\n\n-----------------Inverse Document Frequency-------------------\n";


cout<<"\n IDF = "<<idf;

for(i=1;i<4;i++)

matchh[i]=cntt[i]=flg[i]=0;

cout<<"\n";


}
/**************************************************/



int main()

{


do

{
cout<<"\n************** Menu ****************\n";
cout<<"\n (1) Term Frequency";
cout<<"\n (2) Inverse Document Frequency";
cout<<"\n (3) Exit";
cout<<"\n************************************\n";
cout<<"\n Select from Menu => ";cin>>ch;
switch(ch)

{
```

Here main part I dont want to enter the word , I want to list each word count.

```
    case 1:


            cout<<"\n Enter The Word  => ";
            cin>>word;

            case1();
            break;

    case 2: cout<<"\n Enter The Word  => ";
            cin>>word;
            case2();
            break;

    case 3: exit(0);

}


}

while(ch!=3);

getch();

}
```

Comment: Combinations of C-style IO (like `fscanf`) and C++ style IO (like `std::cin`) may work, but it is probably best to stick with one or the other.

Comment: First of all thank you for reply me , I'm using code blocks and which part I will change ? about std::cin , if(strstr(line,word)!=0) i will change it "strstr" ?

Comment: Please look at my answer for an alternative to using `strstr`.

Comment: I will take the words from file , This is my first question I dont know how can I put here all codes

Comment: I will try to put all codes with new question  same title

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please understand that this is not the place to go into C++ programming basics. You should try to find some good C++ tutorials in your language; this isn't something I can help with however.

Comment: I did all codes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659785/c-word-counter

Comment: I don't think that needed a new question; you could have editted this one, and that would have been ok.

Comment: Your new question is marked as a Duplicate.  You should edit ***this*** question to include all the info, NOT open a new question.

Comment: I fixed this question

Comment: Still I couldn't take all words from file please help

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string`. Plain old C-style strings are worth avoiding, where possible, because they are easy to misuse. C++ strings are much safer and generally simpler to work with.

```
std::string text = "some long line of text";
std::string word = "line";

if (text.find(word) != std::string::npos)
  std::cout << "Found the word!\n";
```

If you have multiple words:

```
std::vector<std::string> words = { "one", "word", "is", "badgers" };

for (const auto& word : words)
  if (text.find(word) !=  std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Found \"" << word << "\"!\n";
```

If you wish to load your words from a file, you can do so entirely using the (relatively) safe C++ io classes and functions.

```
std::ifstream wordfile("where/your/file/is");
std::string word;

while (std::getline(wordfile, word).good())
{
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: Is `std::array<std::vector>` meant to say `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: @interjay yes, well spotted. Fixed now, ta.